# How to exit a never ending process without killing the process

Tags: bash, docker, radius

I'm working with docker at the moment and I'm trying to run a command from rc.local in the Dockerfile but the command doesn't exit unless I kill it manually. Is there a way I can "disown" the process so that I can get to shell and still have the process running by itself?

The command I'm working with is `free radius -X -l /var/log/radius.log` is there a way to maybe add this as a service running in the background?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `<command> &` will put the command to the background. If you also want to run the command even if you close the terminal/log out, run `nohup <command> &`.  But in the latter case, you will have to kill the process manually anyway.

Comment: @ridgy This command works but only when I run it manually from bash, the dockerfile doesn't seem to run the command by itself causing the service to never start...

Comment: Ok, I read the question again. I'm not sure but suppose your command is `radiusd -X -l ...`. The option `-X` is equal to `-sfxx -l stdout` (see manpage), where `-s`means "single server", `-xx` means "print details to stdout", and `-f`means " Do not fork, stay running as a foreground process". The last option keeps `radiusd` from detaching, and thus should only be used when run manually, because otherwise `rc.local`won't continue. If you want more debug information, `-sxx`might work, but you probably have to redirect stdout (I don't know if `-xx` respects `-l`).

Comment: You can also debug an already running radiusd with [raddebug](http://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/raddebug.html)

Comment: I've solved my issue: Rather than using this 

`CMD freeradius -X -l /var/log/radius.log &`

I used:

`CMD freeradius -X -l /var/log/radius.log & \
bash `

This seemed to work, also using a shell script to run the command worked fine also. I'll look into why docker could't run the command when the container runs but running from the shell was fine...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ridgy you can specify `&` after your command to drop it into the background. For my particular case this didn't work. NOTE using `&` needs to go in hand with `bg` so that the process can run in the background the same goes for using ctrl-z to set a background process.